# Object Type doesn't support property or method 'includes' in IE

Tags: angular

My page is displaying in IE properly.But when I am trying to click on links it is not redirecting and showing Type error like:

"Object don't support this property or method 'includes' ".I change includes to index of even it is not redirecting and showing same error message.

Comment: Yes I did like that only.But still I am struggling with that error message.It is showing that error msg in bundle.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the includes and try to use indexOf in your application

```
if(window.location.hash.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.includes` is not supported in IE11. Check the browser support on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). In this case you can include a polyfill, which adds that functionality to all browsers that dont support it.

`Array.includes` [shim](https://github.com/es-shims/array-includes) or [polyfill](https://github.com/kevlatus/polyfill-array-includes)

Answer (score -1):

Internet Explorer don't support includes, we can use like below :

```
(somestring.indexOf("substring")!=-1)
```

got same issue used this and worked for me.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp